# 'Reload' or 'Reconnect' in Cloud Shell Editor - Is there a difference?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terminal, google-cloud-shell

I have noticed that when I return to Google `Cloud Shell Editor` after some time, I see the following two options to re-establish my connection:

- The `Editor` gives the option to **Reload**
- The `Terminal` gives the option to **Reconnect**

What is the difference between these `Reload` and `Reconnect` ?  Both buttons seem to re-establish a connection with both the `Editor` and the `Terminal`, so what is the reason for the different terminology?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the basic difference as when we opt to **RELOAD**, it'll refresh the whole session of the terminal. There you lose unsaved data where it can be a file you're editing or any changes you made in configuration before you lost without saving.
And on other hand, if you use **RECONNECT** it'll try to continue with the same point where you lost your connection. The session will try to reconnect and make you continue with the same point you stopped